# Image resolution capped on 1024x1024 CameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, resolution, aspect-ratio, android-camerax

I am using CameraX to capture images in my Android app. The problem I have is I cant change image resolution. Or I should say I cant change it to higher than 1024x1024.

I am trying to change capture resolution to 1920x1080, using aspect ratio and resolution, but none of combinations I tried worked. If I for example set ratio to 16:9 I am getting 1024x576 resolution.

I followed https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#9 to setup CameraX, so my code is exactly like that, but with different aspect ratio, and adding

```
setTargetResolution(Size(1080, 1920))
```

Comment: If you check the output of `StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSize(int)` does it give you values higher than 1024?

Comment: It returns max of 4640x3480.

Comment: You write about image capture, but the linked example is only about preview?

Comment: @Ertyguy kindly tell me how to use `StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputSize(int)`. for me it is giving compile time error. It is not letting me to run the code. Show some snippets.